# Is there a classification of differential equations over the field of fractions of formal power series? (characteristic 0)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, d-modules

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Consider the field of fractions of formal power series $K:= Frac(k[[T_1,...,T_n]])$. We have the corresponding algebra of differential operators $D = K[\partial_1,\partial_2,...,\partial_n]$ with $[\partial_i,f]= \partial_i f$.

> Is there a classification of finitely generated modules over
>   $D$ for $n>1$?